# How can I save three variables using function and button?

Tags: javascript, html

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/T11l5.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTAmO.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aimnc.png)
I was trying to save the first number of an operation on a variable "num1", then the operation sign on another variable "sign" and then the other number in other variable "num2" for later calculate them. Is that possible considering there is only one function?

I've tried using if/else for solving this problem but it didn't work. So now I need another solution. I know there is other solutions for this problem, but I need this way: work with 3 variables or more.

```js
function soma(){
    let numero1 = document.getElementById("numero1").value;
    let numero2 = document.getElementById("numero2").value;
    let soma = numero1+numero2;
    alert(soma)
}
// function exibir(){
//     let nome = prompt("Qual o seu nome?")
//     alert("Bem vindo, " + nome + "!")
// }
function idade(){
    let anoAtual = 2023
    let idade = 2023 - (prompt("Qual o ano do seu nascimento? "))
    alert("Sua idade: " + idade)
}
function hello(){
    alert("Seja bem-vindo!")
    // console.log("Seja bem-vindo!")
}
function exibir(){
    let primeiro = document.getElementById("primeiro").value;
    let segundo = document.getElementById("segundo").value;
    alert(primeiro + " " + segundo);
}
function inserir(num) {
    let numero = document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML;    
    document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = numero + num;
}

function limpar(){
    document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = "";
}
```

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.principal {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    background-color: rgb(198, 226, 43);
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
#primeiro {
    height: 37.6px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
#segundo {
    height: 37.6px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

button a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.calculadora {
    background-color: rgb(136, 142, 148);
    padding: 7px;
    margin: 3px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
.calculadora button {
    margin: 3px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.calculadora p {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 15px;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>aula 1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body onload="hello()">
    <div class="principal">
        <h1>Aula 1</h1>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="exibir()">Bem-vindo</button>
        <button class="btn btn-info" onclick="idade()">Idade</button>
        <button class="btn btn-light"><a href="https://github.com/lucabarata/mobile1/tree/main/aula1">Acessar</a></button>
        <input id="primeiro" type="text" placeholder="Nome">
        <input id="segundo" type="text" placeholder="Sobrenome">
    </div>
    <div class="calculadora">
        <table>
            <p id="resultado"></p>
            <tr>
                <td><button class="botao" onclick="inserir('7')">7</button></td>
                <td><button class="botao" onclick="inserir('8')">8</button></td>
                <td><button class="botao" onclick="inserir('9')">9</button></td>
                <td><button class="botao" onclick="inserir('*')">X</button></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><button class="botao" onclick="inserir('4')">4</button></td>
                <td><button class="botao" onclick="inserir('5')">5</button></td>
                <td><button class="botao" onclick="inserir('6')">6</button></td>
                <td><button class="botao" onclick="inserir('-')">-</button></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><button class="botao" onclick="inserir('1')">1</button></td>
                <td><button class="botao" onclick="inserir('2')">2</button></td>
                <td><button class="botao" onclick="inserir('3')">3</button></td>
                <td><button class="botao" onclick="inserir('+')">+</button></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td><button class="botao" onclick="inserir('/')">/</button></td>
                <td><button class="botao" onclick="inserir('0')">0</button></td>
                <td><button class="botao" onclick="limpar()">C</button></td>
                <td><button class="botao" onclick="calcular()">=</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <p id="mostraNum1">Num1</p>

    <script src="javascript/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please don't use images, post your own code, something we can actually see and reproduce to see what error you get and guide you from there

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your post needs improvement.

Comment: Declare your variables outside of your functions and event handlers, thereby giving them a [global scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#variable_scope).

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variables outside the function
Example:

```
var hi = ‘hi’;
function sayHi(){
console.log(hi);
}
```

`>>> hi`